# New to Sails.js how can I route to a view without including the layout.ejs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

New to Sails.js I've read over the docs but I don't see a way to NOT include the `layout.ejs` located in `/views/`.

I'm trying to implement Angular into my app and when I go

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{
  controller: 'HomeController',
  templateUrl: '/home'
})
```

So then in my routes I expect to be able to do:

```
'GET /home': { view: 'angular/home.ejs' }
```

But what happens is it loads `home.ejs` but also injects `layout.ejs` so it becomes an endless loop of injecting `layout.ejs` loading angular scripts from layout, then trying to load `home.ejs` which loads `layout.ejs` so on so forth

So how can I do this?

I know I can put views in `/asset/angular/home.html` but I would like to have `.ejs` so that I can render a different view (e.g. user is not logged in) or something.

Any information on how I can render `views` without injecting `layout.ejs` would be great, thanks!

Update:

So by doing this:

```
'GET /home': { 
  view: 'home',
  locals: {
    layout: false
  }
}
```

it makes it work, I don't know if there is a global way so I don't have to flag `layout: false` for each one

Comment: You can put layout : false under /config/view.js to do it globally

Comment: If I do that I get csrf issues @jaumard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To disable layouts globally, you can put `layout : false` under `/config/view.js`.
2. To disable layout individually, leave `/config/view.js` alone and do something like this in your routes:

   ```
   'GET /home': { 
       view: 'home',
       locals: {
           layout: false
       }
   }
   ```